# how to do swipe Webview pages in android

Tags: android, android-webview, swipe

I have a question that I want to Swipe `webView`  with touch in Horizontal Manner with Many Pages. How to implement this in our project? Please suggest me for right result.

Comment: post somelink or screenshot of the webview

Comment: @RahulKhurana i want to swipe in webView . how to do this?

Comment: You can override onTouchListener by placing a transparent View above WebView of same size.

Comment: would you send some example code

Answer (score 0):

Just add a simple OnTouchListener to your webview. Clicking on links, scrollling still works.

Just follow the 3 simple steps:

1 - Make your calling object implement a simple TouchListener:

```
public interface TouchListener  {
    default void onSwipeLeft() {
        Logger.d( "Swipe left default action");  
    }
    default void onSwipeRight() {
        Logger.d( "Swipe right default action");
    }
}
```

2 - In your calling class, add the below OnTouchListener to your webView:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener( new OnSwipeWebviewTouchListener( getActivity(), this));
```

Implement the onSwipeLeft() and onSwipeRight() methods with your functionality.

3 - Use this OnTouchListener:

```
public class OnSwipeWebviewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    public OnSwipeWebviewTouchListener(Context ctx, TouchListener touchListener) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener(touchListener));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private TouchListener touchListener;
        GestureListener(TouchListener touchListener) {
            super();
            this.touchListener = touchListener;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;  // THIS does the trick
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    // You can customize these settings, so 30 is an example
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > 30 && Math.abs(velocityX) > 30) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            touchListener.onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            touchListener.onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > userSettings.swipeYDistanceThreshold && Math.abs(velocityY) > userSettings.swipeYSpeedThreshold) {
                    result = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```